# Build rice wrapper with CMake using cmake custom commands

Tags: cmake

I have a working rice wrapper for c++ library. I need just .cpp file and extconf.rb file to build this wrapper with following commands:

```
ruby extconf.rb
make
```

How to do the same with cmake?

Comment: Call a custom_command?

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to specify a working directory and the path to the `.rb` file better, but basically.

```
add_custom_command(TARGET ${YOUR_TARGET} POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ruby extconf.rb)
add_custom_command(TARGET ${YOUR_TARGET} POST_BUILD
    COMMAND make)
```

More info about `add_custom_command`: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_custom_command.html